# Possible for mapped function types in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a function type in typescript

```
interface ParseFn {
  (param: string): number;
}
```

Is there a way to map function types in TypeScript? Can I do something like

```
type Async<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]>;
}

const myAsyncNumParser: Async<ParseFn> = ...
```

?

Comment: Do you mean [like this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgMRMgbwChlTkAKABwzgFsAuZTMKUAcwEpGQBXWgI2gBuIgF8iRMAE9KKAIKYpIBAB4AKsggAPSCAAmmCgDoTGNpkZwQUjsgC8APmRWpTuyTIbtug8dNRzRlAYaGQ5W0dkYNCAJWQAfj8jMwswiKdUKAB7WmBsFRinbggAN2EJSRl5RWV0LFx8OzCa1TrsPAcRAHou5GlZZqUENob7CmooOkZmVhBOewzs3PzeAWgHIiA) or are you asking for something else?

Comment: The end result seems to be what I want but I guess there’s not really any mapping going on here in the mapped type sense. I didn’t know function types could be extended like that. Nor did I know about the infer operator. Looks like I have some reading to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) in TypeScript completely ignore call and construct signatures, so they won't do what you want.  Instead, you can use [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) introduced in TypeScript 2.8.   Assuming what you want is to take a function type `T` and return a new function type which takes the same parameters but whose return type is wrapped in `Promise<>`, you can do it like this:

```
type Async<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => Promise<R> : never;
type AsyncParseFn = Async<ParseFn>;
// type AsyncParseFn = (param: string) => Promise<number>
```

There are also predefined utility types called [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) and [`ReturnType<T>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) that use such conditional types to get the parameter tuple and return type of a function type.  You could use those, instead, if you prefer:

```
type Async2<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>;
type Async2ParseFn = Async<ParseFn>;
// type Async2ParseFn = (param: string) => Promise<number>
```

Either way should work.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgMRMgbwChlTkAKABwzgFsAuZTMKUAcwEpGQBXWgI2gBuIgF9kRImACelFAEFM0kAgA8AFWQQAHpBAATTBQB0pjG0yM4IaR2QBeAHzJr05-ZJlNOvYZNmoC0ZQGGhkeTsnZBCwgCVkAH5-Y3NLcMjnVCgAe1pgbFVY524IADdhKVkFJRV0LFx8e3CatTrsPEcRAHou5Bk5ZuUENoaHCmooOkZmVhBOB0ycvILeAWhHSUqBxSGAJg0tXQgDI3JTFMC01wyXG3dPUjOAoLQaWghILA1HG6zc-IghQ+PCgIHUVW+nUk-WqexGeDGOxUqnhIChPT6VUGKl2qLGVDe0xY7F+SwBqlWgigGyAA)